# Non-continuity of Levy area

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, rough-path-theory

I am trying to get familiar with Rough Path Theory by reading 'Rough Path Theory and Stochastic Calculus' by Yuzuru Inahama. He argues in favour of Rough Paths as opposed to  Ito integrals as the latter converge only in $L^2(\mu)$ sense. He states (statement 1):

"Each element of $L^2(\mu)$ is just an equivalence class with respect to μ and a single point set is of μ-zero set, the stochastic integral does not have an x-wise meaning."

Furthermore, he states (statement 2):

"Neither is it continuous in x. For example, let us consider Levy’s stochastic area
for two-dimensional Brownian motion

$$ x = (x^1,x^2)\rightarrow \int_{0}^{1}  (x_s^2 dx_s^1-x_s^1dx_s^2 )  $$

is not continuous".

My questions are: What is the simplest way of seeing statement 2? As far as statement 1 is concerned, is there a nice example, ideally with some relevance to other areas such as mathematical finance?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some references for this same result (I couldn't find the article by Sugita referenced in the article), are in ["A Course on Rough Paths"](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-030-41556-3) in Proposition 1.1 and Proposition 1.29 in Lyon's book ["Differential Equations Driven by Rough Paths"](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-540-71285-5)

There exists no separable Banach space $B \subset C([0, 2\pi])$ with the
following properties

1.Sample paths of Brownian motions lie in $B$ almost surely.

2.The map $(f, g) \mapsto\int_{0}^{\cdot}f(t)\dot{g}(t) dt$ defined on smooth functions extends to a continuous map from $B \times B$ into the space of continuous functions on $[0, 2\pi]$.

**Proof**

Fix iid standard Gaussians $(\xi_{n})_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}$ and orthonormal basis $e_{n}$ for the Cameron–Martin space of Brownian motion $W^{1,2}_{0}([0,2\pi])$

$$e_{0}(t)=\frac{t}{\sqrt{2\pi}},e_{n}(t)=\frac{\sin(kt)}{k\sqrt{pi}},e_{-n}(t)=\frac{\cos(kt)}{k\sqrt{pi}},n>0.$$
Then the processes
$$X_{t}^{N}=e_{0}\xi_{0}+\sum_{n=1}^{N} e_{n}\xi_{n}+e_{-n}\xi_{-n}\text{ and } Y_{t}^{N}=e_{0}\xi_{0}+\sum_{n=1}^{N}e_{n}\xi_{-n}-e_{-n}\xi_{n},$$

are approximations to two Brownian motions $X_{t},Y_{t}$. On the other hand,

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi }X^{N}_{t}dY^{N}_{t}=\frac{\xi_{0}^{2}}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{\xi_{n}^{2}+\xi_{-n}^{2}}{n}\to +\infty$$

and

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi }Y^{N}_{t}dX^{N}_{t}=\frac{\xi_{0}^{2}}{2}-\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{\xi_{n}^{2}+\xi_{-n}^{2}}{n}\to -\infty.$$

**Example**
Here we do the two-dimensional counterexample in the OP. We follow [On the Importance of the Levy Area for Studying the
Limits of Functions of Converging Stochastic Processes.
Application to Homogenization](https://inria.hal.science/inria-00092419/file/lejay-lyons.pdf) in pg.5. We consider $$X^{1,n}_{t}=B^{1}_{t}+\frac{\cos(n^{2}t)}{n},X^{2,n}_{t}=B^{2}_{t}+\frac{\sin(n^{2}t)}{n}.$$

This pair converges to the Brownian motion $(B^{1}_{t},B^{2}_{t})$. However, the Lévy area is

$$A(X^{1,n},X^{2,n})=\int X^{2,n}_{t} dX^{1,n}_{t}-\int X^{1,n}_{t} dX^{2,n}_{t}$$

$$=A(B^1,B^{2})+A(\frac{\sin(n^{2}t)}{n},\frac{\cos(n^{2}t)}{n})+\int B^{2}_{t}n\sin(n^{2}t)dt+\int \frac{\cos(n^{2}t)}{n} dB^{1}_{t}$$

$$-\int B^{1}_{t}(-n\cos(n^{2}t)dt)-\int \frac{\sin(n^{2}t)}{n} dB^{2}_{t}.$$

We have

$$A(\frac{\sin(n^{2}t)}{n},\frac{\cos(n^{2}t)}{n})=\pi t$$

and that two of the integrals diverge. So the Lévy area of the approximation doesn't converge to the limit Lévy area $A(B^1,B^{2})$, which is only defined in the $L^{2}$-sense.

Comment: many thx! A few questions, if you don't mind:

Comment: (1) Your proof of divergence of the Levy area seems to go through not just for BM paths but applies to smooth paths as well, correct? (2)  $ A(B^1,B^2)$ is not defined in a Rieman Stielges sense,right (see first part of you explanation) ? Do you mean the Ito/Stratanovich integral here?

Comment: (3) Is there a typo?: $  {∫B^2_t \ n \ cos(n2t)dt} $ should be $ -{∫B^2_t \ n \ sin(n2t)dt}$ ?

Comment: @alexl (1) yes, as long as we add the sin/cos terms, which is the original counterexample by T.Lyons.

Comment: @alexl (2)Yes, we can only define it in the L2-sense via Itô (eg. see Wiener chaos mulitple integrals). (If we use rough paths, then we do get continuity in the p-variation norm for p<2).

Comment: @alexl (3) yes fixed.